# Is it possible to disable Symfony framework support in NetBeans 6.8?

Tags: php, ide, netbeans, symfony1, netbeans6.8

Put simply: it causes a massive memory leak within an hour if I work on a Symfony project, and I don't use any of the features that it provides. I've looked through all of the menus and can't seem to see an option to disable support for it.

Has anyone attempted or managed to remove this module from the IDE? I quite like NetBeans, but on the rare occasions when I need to work with a Symfony project it's causing me quite a headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Tools, Plugins menu, there you can deactivate or uninstall the installed plugins (PHP Symfony Framework is one of these).

Comment: I only have the entire PHP plugin, which lists Symfony as a module inside that - if I remove the plugin I'll also remove all PHP support. Is it possible to just remove the module from that plugin?

Comment: Hmmm, weird, I'm using Netbeans 6.8 as well and if I go to Tools, Plugins and check the Installed plugins tab, then there's a separate listing for the Symfony framework which can be deactivated/uninstalled separately. I'll upload a screenshot when I'm home (behind very restrictive firewall at the moment).

Comment: Ah ha! I may have just fixed it. I removed the existing PHP plugin, restarted the IDE, and pulled down a new list of plugins. I was then able to see what you describe, and install solely the PHP plugin. I believe my plugin must have been carried over from the beta/RC version of 6.8, and it has since been split. Thanks muchly for the help! :)